# How can I execute multiple SQL commands using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I was trying to use this code two run two commands in one connection, which I couldn't do, here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(""))
{           
    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT quatro, tres FROM todos_cp ORDER BY quatro, tres ";

    using (SqlCommand RetriveCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = RetriveCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string coluna = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("quatro"));
            string coluna1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("tres"));

            Boolean ElementDisplayed;

            try
            {
            }    
            catch (NoSuchElementException i)
            {
                ElementDisplayed = false;
                GDataPicker();
                for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    string query2 = @"INSERT INTO table_teste1(Rua, CodigoPostal, Distrito, Concelho, Freguesia, GPS) VALUES(" + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Rua"].Value + "', " + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Código Postal"].Value + "', " + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Distrito"].Value + "', " + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Concelho"].Value + "', " + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Freguesia"].Value + "', " + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["GPS"].Value + "');";

                    for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
                        {
                            string query2 = @"INSERT INTO table_teste1 (Rua, CodigoPostal,Distrito,Concelho,Freguesia,GPS ) VALUES (" + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Rua"].Value + "', " + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Código Postal"].Value + "', "+ "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Distrito"].Value + "', "+ "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Concelho"].Value + "', "+ "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Freguesia"].Value + "', "+ "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["GPS"].Value + "');";


                            using(SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query2,connection))
                            {

                                InsertCommand.CommandText = query2;
                                InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();       
    }
}
```

My problem is most likely in the lines where I do:

```
InsertCommand.CommandText = query2;
InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And says i already have one datareader.

Help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: unrelated: please please don't concatenate user data (from the grid) directly into SQL - that's a huge "SQL injection" risk, and makes it trivial to abuse your database completely

Comment: but can you see what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Well: what currently happens? you haven't actually told us. Does it complain about an "active reader"?

Comment: yes i already solved the problem i was trying to do everything  in one loop with only one connection, so if i had  another connection done, even so i m gonna work a little on my code

Answer (score 0):

Append you second command in "query2". As it is inline query Sql will consider that as two different query (Append after semicolon) and will execute in the same connection